# How to add a Tooltip to the legend elements of a chart in dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I have been quite a while already looking for a way to add a tool tip to the legend elements of a chart in dimple.js with no success.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way of creating a tooltip for the legend, but, after drawing you can select all the shapes and create a tooltip for each one. For example:

```
        // code creating one tooltip
div var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

// code that adds an event listener to each rectangle in your legend:
myLegend.shapes.selectAll("rect")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {        
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```

Dimple reference for legend.shapes: [legend.shapes](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.legend#shapes)

Code in the example is mostly copied from Mike Bostock's example: [simple d3 tooltips](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369)